# Can't import ActionBarCompat from Android Support Library using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar-compat

I am using Android Studio and have followed [this article from google](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) as well as [some other articles](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-add-actionbarcompat-to-your.html) discussing how to use the new ActionBarCompat.

I have downloaded the support library (Rev. 18) in Android SDK Manager and added the following in my *build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Now I'm trying to import the Support Library API and extend ActionBarActivity in my code,
however, this is what showed up

[image]
[image]

which is not what it is supposed to be

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Any Help?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem. I followed this step to solved it, in Android Studio - **Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files**.

[image]

**Edit:**
Sorry, I forgot add this:
After *Sync Project with Gradle Files* follow this steps:

- Right mouse click for your project and select **Open Module Settings**

[image]

- After that, select dependencies tab

[image]

- In the end - selec your library:

[image]

This should work.