# Struggling to install 'ActionBarSherlock'

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I have read many How-To's RE ActionBarSherlock, the majority on SO. I tried [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19668480/1656909) but I get this error:
[image]
OK, not so bad, back to SO to find out how to change the reference to the manifest file. [This is what I come across](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097436/1656909) but this seems to make things worse:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Jonny Wright\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\res\all\debug -A D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\assets\debug -m -J D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\source\r\debug -F D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\libs\Proficio-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.traffisoft.proficio.app --output-text-symbols D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
    D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
    D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
    D:\Development\Android\Proficio\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
```

I have recently updated Android Studio from a much older version, has the default folder structure changed since then? I did notice that the package name is laid out slightly differently to how I have seen before;

```
com.xxx.yyy.zzz
```

instead of

```
com.xxx.yyy
```

build.gradle file;

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

I would also like to point out this is a brand new Android Studio project, all I have done is try to get ABS working.

Comment: Can you post your "build.gradle" file?

Comment: Is your manifest file under `src/main/`?

Comment: Its under `AppName/app/src/main/`